# Does Skobbler / Scout support routes with waypoints, multiple routes with different colors and map legend

Tags: android, xamarin, skmaps

Does the Skobbler / Scout Android SDK support routes with waypoints? From the api I can only see a start and end point in the route settings.

Also, is it possible to plot multiple routes with different colors on the map at the same time and have a map legend to indicate what the different colors represent?

Thanks.

Comment: Isnt this off-topic???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 2.4 (this version will be out soon), there will be viaPoints – waypoints – for creating a route with intermediate stops and adding/removing waypoints to an already existing route.

As for the second question, you'll find the answer here: [How to change the color of the route in Skobbler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517924/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-route-in-skobbler)

Note: for next time focus on adding only technical questions here and for the general ones send an email at dev@skobbler.com

Comment: Thanks for the info. Appreciated. Are you a Skobbler dev? I sent an email to that address a few days ago but have yet to receive a reply, hence reaching out via other means.

Comment: I'm working for skobbler (support team). We'll reply to your email today (sorry for delay)