# Change width of route in Skobblers SKMaps for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, skmaps

I would like to change the route width of a calculated route. Using Skobblers SKMaps Framework.

I've successfully used this thread ([How to change the color of the route in Skobbler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25517924/how-to-change-the-color-of-the-route-in-skobbler)) to change the route color, but if I change the width in the daystyle.json nothing seems to change. I tried all kinds of values (1.0, 1.9, 2.5, 10.0, 100.0) but the width remains the same. No matter if the map is in navigation mode or not.

Comment: Please attach your style file (or the a snippet from style file where you define your route style) so that we can see what you are changing

Answer (score 2):

The id for the route is 0. You need to change the width values for the 0 attribute. In this example the width is set to 2.0 for the zoom level 4:

```
{
            "id" : "0.4",
            "isattribute" : true,
            "line" : 
            {
                "fill" : 
                {
                    "color" : "FF0000",
                    "width" : 2.0
                },
                "outline" : 
                {
                    "color" : "0080FF",
                    "width" : 1.0
                },
            }
        },
```

Comment: That did it. I didn't realise the .4 was the zoom level. I only changed the .4 width before. After changing all the widths for 0.4 ... 0.18 it worked. Thanks for you response.